# Angular Scheduler quick info template moves above calendar frame

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sass, scheduler

I was testing calendar that I made with Angular Scheduler library and found out that quick info template are appearing above calendar's frame. I need to improve that bug. How can I do this?

P.S. - It's a new feature in Angular Scheduler with these quick info templates.

html file

```
<div *ngIf="accessChecker.isGranted('view', 'scheduler') | async" class="">
  <div class="control-section">
    <ejs-schedule #scheduleObj width='100%' height='600px' [selectedDate]="selectedDate" [readonly]=true
                  [showHeaderBar]="false" [eventSettings]="eventSettings" [firstDayOfWeek]="1">
      <e-resources>
        <e-resource field='RoomId' title='Room Type' name='MeetingRoom' textField='Name' idField='Id'
                    colorField='Color' [dataSource]='roomData'>
        </e-resource>
      </e-resources>
      <!-- Header template -->

      <ng-template style="position: relative;" #quickInfoTemplatesHeader let-data>
        <div class="quick-info-header-content" [ngStyle]="getHeaderStyles(data)">
          <div><p style="font-size: 20px; margin:15px">Treeningute info</p></div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <!-- Content Template -->
      <ng-template style="position: relative;" #quickInfoTemplatesContent let-data>
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="data.elementType == 'cell' ? cellContent : eventContent"
                      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{data:data}"></ng-container>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template style="position: relative;" #cellContent let-data="data">
        <div class="quick-info-content">
          <div class="e-cell-content">
            <div class="content-area">
              <ejs-textbox #titleObj id="title" placeholder="Title"></ejs-textbox>
            </div>
            <div class="content-area">
              <ejs-dropdownlist id='eventType' #eventTypeObj [dataSource]='roomData' [fields]='roomFields'
                                placeholder='Choose Type' index="{{0}}" popupHeight="200px"></ejs-dropdownlist>
            </div>
            <div class="content-area">
              <ejs-textbox #notesObj id="notes" placeholder="Notes"></ejs-textbox>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template style="position: relative;" #eventContent let-data="data">
        <div class="quick-info-content">
          <div class="event-content">
            <div class="meeting-type-wrap">
              <label>Pealkiri</label>:
              <span>{{data.Subject}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="meeting-subject-wrap">
              <label>Koht</label>:
              <span>{{getEventType(data)}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="notes-wrap">
              <label>Treenigute aeg</label>:
              <span>{{data.Description}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="notes-wrap">
              <div class="row">
                <label>Treeningu </label>:
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Aktiveerida koodi">
                <input type="checkbox">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <!-- Footer Template -->
      <ng-template style="position: relative;" #quickInfoTemplatesFooter let-data>
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="data.elementType == 'cell' ? cellFooter : eventFooter"
                      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{data:data}"></ng-container>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template #cellFooter let-data="data">
        <div class="e-cell-footer">
          <button ejs-button id="more-details" cssClass="e-flat" (click)="buttonClickActions($event)">More
            Details
          </button>
          <button ejs-button id="add" cssClass="e-flat" [isPrimary]="true"
                  (click)="buttonClickActions($event)">Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template style="position: relative;" #eventFooter let-data="data">
        <div class="e-event-footer">
          <button ejs-button id="more-details" cssClass="e-flat" (click)="buttonClickActions($event)">Peatu treeningut
          </button>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <e-views>
        <e-view option="Month"></e-view>
      </e-views>
    </ejs-schedule>
  </div>
</div>
```

component file

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {extend, Internationalization} from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import {DropDownListComponent} from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns';
import {TextBoxComponent} from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs';
import {
  ScheduleComponent, MonthService, DayService, WeekService, WorkWeekService, AgendaService,
  MonthAgendaService, ResourcesModel, CellClickEventArgs, CurrentAction, EventSettingsModel
} from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-schedule';
import {quickInfoTemplateData} from './data';
import {NbAccessChecker} from '@nebular/security';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-scheduler',
  templateUrl: 'scheduler.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['scheduler.component.scss'],
  providers: [DayService, WeekService, WorkWeekService, MonthService, AgendaService, MonthAgendaService],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class SchedulerComponent {
  @ViewChild('scheduleObj')
  public scheduleObj: ScheduleComponent;
  @ViewChild('eventTypeObj')
  public eventTypeObj: DropDownListComponent;
  @ViewChild('titleObj')
  public titleObj: TextBoxComponent;
  @ViewChild('notesObj')
  public notesObj: TextBoxComponent;
  public eventSettings: EventSettingsModel = {dataSource: <Object[]>extend([], quickInfoTemplateData, null, true)};
  public selectedDate: Date = new Date(2020, 0, 9);
  public intl: Internationalization = new Internationalization();
  public roomFields: Object = {text: 'Name', value: 'Id'};
  public roomData: Object[] = [
    {Name: 'Jammy', Id: 1, Capacity: 20, Color: '#ea7a57', Type: 'Conference'},
    {Name: 'Tweety', Id: 2, Capacity: 7, Color: '#7fa900', Type: 'Cabin'},
    {Name: 'Nestle', Id: 3, Capacity: 5, Color: '#5978ee', Type: 'Cabin'},
    {Name: 'Phoenix', Id: 4, Capacity: 15, Color: '#fec200', Type: 'Conference'},
    {Name: 'Mission', Id: 5, Capacity: 25, Color: '#df5286', Type: 'Conference'},
    {Name: 'Hangout', Id: 6, Capacity: 10, Color: '#00bdae', Type: 'Cabin'},
    {Name: 'zalypa', Id: 7, Capacity: 20, Color: '#865fcf', Type: 'Conference'},
    {Name: 'Rainbow', Id: 8, Capacity: 8, Color: '#1aaa55', Type: 'Cabin'},
    {Name: 'Swarm', Id: 9, Capacity: 30, Color: '#df5286', Type: 'Conference'},
    {Name: 'Photogenic', Id: 10, Capacity: 25, Color: '#710193', Type: 'Conference'}
  ];

  constructor(public accessChecker: NbAccessChecker) {

  }

  public getResourceData(data: { [key: string]: Object }): { [key: string]: Object } {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
    const resources: ResourcesModel = this.scheduleObj.getResourceCollections()[0];
    const resourceData: { [key: string]: Object } = (resources.dataSource as Object[]).filter((resource: { [key: string]: Object }) =>
      resource.Id === data.RoomId)[0] as { [key: string]: Object };
    return resourceData;
  }


  public getHeaderStyles(data: { [key: string]: Object }): Object {
    if (data.elementType === 'cell') {
      return {'align-items': 'center', 'color': '#919191'};
    } else {
      const resourceData: { [key: string]: Object } = this.getResourceData(data);
      return {'background': resourceData.Color, 'color': '#FFFFFF'};
    }
  }

  public getHeaderTitle(data: { [key: string]: Object }): string {
    return (data.elementType === 'cell') ? 'Add Appointment' : 'Appointment Details';
  }

  public getHeaderDetails(data: { [key: string]: Date }): string {
    return this.intl.formatDate(data.StartTime, {type: 'date', skeleton: 'full'}) + ' (' +
      this.intl.formatDate(data.StartTime, {skeleton: 'hm'}) + ' - ' +
      this.intl.formatDate(data.EndTime, {skeleton: 'hm'}) + ')';

  }

  public getEventType(data: { [key: string]: string }): string {
    const resourceData: { [key: string]: Object } = this.getResourceData(data);
    return resourceData.Name as string;
  }

  public buttonClickActions(e: Event) {
    const quickPopup: HTMLElement = this.scheduleObj.element.querySelector('.e-quick-popup-wrapper') as HTMLElement;
    const getSlotData: Function = (): { [key: string]: Object } => {
      const cellDetails: CellClickEventArgs = this.scheduleObj.getCellDetails(this.scheduleObj.getSelectedElements());
      const addObj: { [key: string]: Object } = {};
      addObj.Id = this.scheduleObj.getEventMaxID();
      addObj.Subject = this.titleObj.value;
      addObj.StartTime = new Date(+cellDetails.startTime);
      addObj.EndTime = new Date(+cellDetails.endTime);
      addObj.Description = this.notesObj.value;
      addObj.RoomId = this.eventTypeObj.value;
      return addObj;
    };
    if ((e.target as HTMLElement).id === 'add') {
      const addObj: { [key: string]: Object } = getSlotData();
      this.scheduleObj.addEvent(addObj);
    } else if ((e.target as HTMLElement).id === 'delete') {
      const eventDetails: { [key: string]: Object } = this.scheduleObj.activeEventData.event as { [key: string]: Object };
      let currentAction: CurrentAction;
      if (eventDetails.RecurrenceRule) {
        currentAction = 'DeleteOccurrence';
      }
      this.scheduleObj.deleteEvent(eventDetails, currentAction);
    } else {
      const isCellPopup: boolean = quickPopup.firstElementChild.classList.contains('e-cell-popup');
      const eventDetails: { [key: string]: Object } = isCellPopup ? getSlotData() :
        this.scheduleObj.activeEventData.event as { [key: string]: Object };
      let currentAction: CurrentAction = isCellPopup ? 'Add' : 'Save';
      if (eventDetails.RecurrenceRule) {
        currentAction = 'EditOccurrence';
      }
      this.scheduleObj.openEditor(eventDetails, currentAction, true);
    }
    this.scheduleObj.closeQuickInfoPopup();
  }
}
```

module file

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FullCalendarModule} from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import {SchedulerComponent} from './scheduler.component';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {NbButtonModule, NbCardModule, NbInputModule} from '@nebular/theme';
import {ContextMenuAllModule, ToolbarAllModule, TreeViewModule} from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-navigations';
import {ScheduleAllModule, RecurrenceEditorAllModule} from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-schedule';
import {ButtonAllModule, CheckBoxAllModule} from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons';
import {
  MaskedTextBoxModule,
  NumericTextBoxAllModule,
  TextBoxAllModule,
  UploaderAllModule
} from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs';
import {DropDownListAllModule, MultiSelectAllModule} from "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns";
import {DatePickerAllModule, DateTimePickerAllModule, TimePickerAllModule} from "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars";

FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([
  dayGridPlugin,
  timeGridPlugin,
  listPlugin,
  interactionPlugin,
]);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SchedulerComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, ScheduleAllModule, RecurrenceEditorAllModule,
    NumericTextBoxAllModule, TextBoxAllModule, DatePickerAllModule,
    TimePickerAllModule, DateTimePickerAllModule, CheckBoxAllModule,
    ToolbarAllModule, DropDownListAllModule, ContextMenuAllModule,
    MaskedTextBoxModule, UploaderAllModule, MultiSelectAllModule, TreeViewModule, ButtonAllModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [SchedulerComponent],
})
export class SchedulerModule {
}
```

calendar picture without bug

[image]

calendar picture with bug

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply write to `ejs-schedule` inline `style="overflow: visible"` and our quick info templates start working correctly!

[image]

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.